# Visual Studio: Xamarin - Error starting Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019, amd-processor

Problem encountered on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/xamarin/hello-world-tutorial/devicesetup

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

Using the Hello World xamarin example in Visual Studio - I'm unable to start the Android Emulator.

When I click on the Run button in the Android Device Manager - the error appears immediately (See attached)

Error-AndroidDeviceManager (Emulator including Google Play/Google API)
[image]

Emulator error

Device error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=4b63b139-cc77-4b66-9200-0d25f8fc545e'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

Same Error when Emulator is not using Google Play/Google API

[image]

Same Error when Emulator is not using Google Play/Google API

[image]

Windows Specifications
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1909

Processor
AMD Ryzen 9

Task Manager:
Performance: Virtualization is Enabled

cmd - systeminfo:
Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Visual Studio 2019
[image]

Windows Features On/Off (see attached - shows Hyper V / Virtualization enabled as per documentation):
WindowsFeatures
[image]

I tried this way too - adding the Virtual Machine Platform - same error
[image]

Android SDK Settings

[image: Android SDK - Platform]

[image: Android SDK - Tools - part 1]

[image: Android SDK - Tools - part 2]

[image: Android SDK - Tools - part 3]

Android SDK Version:
[image]

Could the issue be related to the Android SDK Tools - only showing *Android SDK Command-line Tools* versions 1.0 to 2.1?
Could the issue be related to Android Repository perhaps missing on the bottom right hand side?
[image]

I've now also included the Android SDK Repository under the tools - but this is still not coming through:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at solutions in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1175370/xamarin-android-phone-emulation-not-working.html) may help.

Comment: thanks Jack - that's helpful. I took a look at the thread, looks like I've done the same - I double checked the Android SDK - looks okay? I'll update main message with screenshots of my Android SDK settings.

Comment: Are you using the latest visual-studio? Can you try to create a new emulator without check Google Play?

Comment: yes - latest version of Visual Studio - VS 2019 - I'll add a screenshot with the details to the main message.

I tried without Google play - same exact error, again I'll add a screenshot with the details to the main message.

I do think the issues lie with the settings somewhere - but unsure exactly which settings need updating.

Comment: It looks like everything is installed well on your side. You can report a problem inside Visual-Studio and get more help.

Comment: Thanks - I raised it a couple of days ago.. but no response yet.
https://github.com/xamarin/get-started/issues/33

Comment: I think you should report this problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: thanks for this suggestion - I've just done that too:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1198435/visual-studio-2019-xamarin-error-starting-android.html

Comment: Yes, wait response there.

Answer (score 6):

You should also check **Virtual Machine Platform** in **Turn Windows features on  or off**. Also, note that the tutorial that you linked to use an Android device for USB debugging.

**EDIT**
Here are my Android SDK Manager settings
Platform Settings

[image: Platforms tab]

Tools

[image: Tools tab]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - I've updated my Virtual Machine Platform - but same error appears. I'll update the main query with screenshot, in case there's anything else that needs to be updated.

I also have tried the other option of using an Android device directly - which works fine - no issues there, but I wanted to get the Android Emulator working in the best way, saves me having to deploy on to my own device each time.

Comment: FYI - the link I shared describes both debugging using a physical Android device and using the Android Emulator.

Comment: You appear to have different settings in Tools than I have. Make sure that you have the latest update of Android SDK Manager and Android Device Manager. As a comparison I have: Windows 10 Core i7, Device Manager version16.6.0.48. Finally it helps to just create a new emulator in Device Manager. I've had to do this fairly recently.

Comment: thanks for this - can you post a screenshot of your settings that I could try and update?
Android SDK Manager looks to be the latest. 

How do I check/update the Android Device Manager?
Also, can you send a screenshot of your Emulator in Android Device Manager? For the emulator, I setup using the default selection, I can try your setup in case it helps.

Comment: Added pictures of SDK Manager. You can check your version under the settings on the lower right of the Android SDK and Tools window.

Comment: Thank you! I've added Android SDK Manager screenshots to the main message too. 
My Android SDK Manager is 16.7.0.13

My Android SDK Tools - only showing Android SDK Command-line Tools versions 1.0 to 2.1... is that correct? 
The Android Repository is showing on the bottom right hand side - again not sure if this is related either.

Answer (score 5):

I had also the same problem, but I have already fixed as next process.

1. disable both [Hyper-V] and [Windows Hypervisor Platform].
2. restart PC.
3. enable both [Hyper-V] and [Windows Hypervisor Platform].
4. restart PC.

Answer (score 5):

1. Disable the hyper-v via the following command on command line and reboot.

   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
2. Enable it back with the following command and reboot.

   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

Now my emulator runs!

It seems like there is some kind of conflict with virtualization as per [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/run-hyper-v-and-vmware-virtual-machines-on-windows-10) and it effects creating Linux VMs too but these steps clears it.

The answer by suzukimi is right but I provided the commands and some additional info.

Comment: these cmds are the solution indeed. below cmd from Vitenuto is the reason causing this error. I am not sure the difference. they look same cmd

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, so I went to my UEFI settings and I realized that my  SVM Mode was disabled. I don't know what motherboard you have but for Gigabyte this usually is in:

`M.I.T → Advanced CPU Core Settings → SVM Mode`

Comment: Thanks for this - using an ASUS motherboard, I already have SVM Enabled in the UEFI settings: ______
 ______
Advanced -> CPU Configuration -> SVM Mode
 ______

I believe this is also shown in the command prompt that I highlighted earlier:
 ______

command prompt, cmd: systeminfo
 ______
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
 ______
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
 ______
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
 ______
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, solved it by turning on the virtualization in the bios

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for 2 days. I even installed Android Studio and run its own emulator to make sure the issue is not Xamarin. Finally it is solved. In my Dell laptop running Windows 10 with Hyper-V installed, there are two issues causing this:

1. Run Command prompt in Admin mode. type `bcdedit`. On the last entry all the way down, make sure `hypervisorlaunchtype` is **Off**. By default it is set to Auto.
   To change this setting, type:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

[image: Admin Prompt]

2. Make sure to run the emulator **on the laptop screen**. Not on any other monitor. Somehow Android emulator crashed my laptop graphics driver when it is on other monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after I brainlessly type some command which ADB I think recommend it to me. After a while a realize, that even WSL does not work (Ubuntu in WSL and Docker) so I started to troubleshoot this one and finaly find solution

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

[source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5363#issuecomment-640337948)

this typing in powershell fix all issues for me with Hyper-V and WSL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue turns out the issue was that the intel HAXM wasn't installing properly from the SDK manager window.
So I downloaded the Installer directly from the repo. and installed it via the exe.

here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Restarted Visual studio. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS and enable Virtualization Technology and of course also make sure the Windows Feature (Hyper-V is installed - all components).

In my case, BIOS was reset when I changed my CPU battery.

Comment: Don't know why it is downvoted when I actually experienced it and fixed it this way. It may not help the OP. But this is one of the solutions for the above problem. I got the same error and I enabled Virtualization it from the BIOS to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This recently happened to me. After some research, I discovered that Microsoft Hyper V was the issue, but the machine I was trying to use it on was Windows 10 Home edition. It had to be Professional, Enterprise, etc. It's not compatible with the version of Windows. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide a source?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what fixed it was putting android device manager on my second monitor and starting the emulator there.