# VisualStudio2019 SDK Android Manager dosnt Start, instead giveng Warning: Gerätefehler: value ('emu.uuid=c1d2555f-5c69-44bc-ae95-56d2f66aaac1'), onl

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-sdk-tools, amd-processor, android-sdk-manager

The Complete Warning:

```
Gerätefehler: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=c1d2555f-5c69-44bc-ae95-56d2f66aaac1'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
```

I have a AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 1700X Eight-Core Processor 3.40 GHz 16,0 GB Processor.

Pictures:

- The SDK Manager:
  [image: The SDK Manager]
- When i click the Start Button:
  [image: When i click the Start Button]

Comment: there are **numerous** existing questions on this issue.  Please search before posting.  https://www.google.com/search?q=only+'qemu.'+properties+are+supported+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I forgot to activate the Visualization in my UEFI/ BIOS. I use the Uefi msi 5.0.

Here is a Video, how to solve it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9kXjf_Hjq0

Have fun in Xamarin Development!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may caused by the video card (AMD Radeon RX580) with outdated drivers.
Update the drivers with "AMD Adrenalin 2020 Edition" and reboot.
Run the android emulator and if you get a GPU error set hw.gpu.mode = off in the emulator properties.

Comment: Hey, i have Nvidia Video Card and a AMD Processor, but both are on the newest version.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999238/visual-studio-xamarin-error-starting-android-emulator